# Editing results in peer review message

Tags: support, review, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

Every time I edit someone else's posts this message appears post-submission:

```
     Thanks for your edit!
     This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.
```

Do I have to reach a certain number of reputation points before my edits do not need to be peer reviewed? And, in keeping with the topic, how can *I* peer review other's edits?

Answer (score 1):

From the [FAQ link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) at the top of every page:

> 2000   Edit other people’s posts, vote to approve or reject suggested edits

Comment: Click links are too much work ;) Thanks for the reference!